# Image Upload issue in Retrofit 2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2

Am a beginner to android, am trying to upload image from my device and while uploading it am facing issue, and there is no response from Api. In postman I have uploaded the image its working fine but how can I achieve this in android studio. below is my main java. please help me to solve the issue

```
public class TheProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonUpload;
    UserNumber userNumber;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_profile);

        buttonUpload = findViewById(R.id.btn_upload_file);
        userNumber = ApiNetClient.getRetrofits().create(UserNumber.class);

        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();

            uploadFile(uri);

        }
    }
    private void uploadFile(Uri uriFile) {
        File file = new File(getRealPath(uriFile));
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(uriFile)), file);

        MultipartBody.Part profileImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image",file.getName(),requestBody);

        Call<ResponseImages> call = userNumber.UploadImage(profileImage);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseImages>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseImages> call, Response<ResponseImages> response) {

                ResponseImages response1= response.body();

                if (response.isSuccessful()){

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    String successResponse = gson.toJson(response.body());
                    Toast.makeText(TheProfileActivity.this, successResponse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(TheProfileActivity.this, "no resp", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseImages> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }
    private String getRealPath(Uri contentUri){

        String[]  proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this,contentUri,proj,null,null,null);
        Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

        assert cursor != null;
        int columIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String result = cursor.getString(columIndex);
        cursor.close();

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is Is Interface class

```
@Multipart
    @POST("Upload_Image")
    Call<ResponseImages> UploadImage(
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Comment: can u log `file.getName()` are u getting correct result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this maybe it works:

Instead of getting filepath try getting inputstream from uri:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(Urifile);
```

Now convert this stream to `bytearray` and upload to server

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
@Multipart
@POST("Upload_Image")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadImage(@Part("file\"; fileName=\"myFile.png\" ")RequestBody requestBodyFile, @Part("image") RequestBody requestBodyJson);


File imgFile = new File("YOUR IMAGE FILE PATH");
RequestBody requestBodyFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), imgFile);
RequestBody requestBodyJson = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
                  retrofitClient.getJsonObject(uploadRequest));



Call<ResponseBody> uploadBundle = uploadImpl.uploadImage(requestBodyFile, requestBodyJson);
Response<BaseResponse> response = uploadBundle.execute();
```

Comment: RequestBody requestBodyJson = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),
                  retrofitClient.getJsonObject(uploadRequest)); what is uploadrequest